# How to make text divided spacing on a line equally?

Tags: spacing

Here is an example I am trying to accomplish. [image]

How would I latex the second line where it is 
 `overdamped ----- critically damped ------ underdamped`

Thanks for the help I appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You might have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) if you wish to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some easy options:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% Just for this example
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(b)]
  \item{}[3 pts.] Now suppose $m = 1$, $c = 1$ and $k = 100$. This system is (\textbf{circle one}):

  overdamped \hfill critically damped \hfill underdamped%

  \item{}[3 pts.] Now suppose $m = 1$, $c = 1$ and $k = 100$. This system is (\textbf{circle one}):

  \makebox[0pt][l]{overdamped} \hfill \makebox[0pt][c]{critically damped} \hfill \makebox[0pt][r]{underdamped}%
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The first one inserts `\hfill` between each option, making the gaps stretch out evenly. The second one inserts the same while setting each item in a zero-width box. The makes the *items* stretch out evenly as opposed to the *gaps*.

The latter output is also possible using a `tabular` or [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx).